# Getting Expected an assignment or function call while animating React Component

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, anime.js

[image: This is the Error I am getting on Compiling.]

This is the SS of error I am getting on Compile time.

I want to add Animations in my React project and Used anime.js for that purpose. But, I am facing a Issue.

```
export default (function () {
const e = document.documentElement; 
if (
 (e.classList.remove("no-js"),
 e.classList.add("js"),
 document.body.classList.contains("has-animations"))
 ) {
e.classList.add("anime-ready"),     >>>>// Getting Error in this line..
  anime
    .timeline({ targets: ".hero-figure-box-05" })
    .add({
      duration: 400,
      easing: "easeInOutExpo",
      scaleX: [0.05, 0.05],
      scaleY: [0, 1],
      perspective: "500px",
      delay: anime.random(0, 400),
    })
    .add({ duration: 400, easing: "easeInOutExpo", scaleX: 1 })
    .add({
      duration: 800,
      rotateY: "-15deg",
      rotateX: "8deg",
      rotateZ: "-1deg",
    }),
  anime
    .timeline({ targets: ".hero-figure-box-06, .hero-figure-box-07" })
    .add({
      duration: 400,
      easing: "easeInOutExpo",
      scaleX: [0.05, 0.05],
      scaleY: [0, 1],
      perspective: "500px",
      delay: anime.random(0, 400),
    })
    .add({ duration: 400, easing: "easeInOutExpo", scaleX: 1 })
    .add({ duration: 800, rotateZ: "20deg" }),
 }
})();
```

This is showing a issue which is

**Line 12:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions**

Comment: Does this `ScrollReveal())` look ok to you? I mean the extra parentheses `)`

Comment: @Molda Actually I forgot to add the starting Parentheses there Please look at it now

Comment: I have removed the unnecessary code Please look at it now.

Comment: So now the line ends with  `...ScrollReveal()).reveal` followed by another line `".feature, .....` so when you put it on a single line it looks like this `...ScrollReveal()).reveal ".feature, .....` Does that look ok to you? I mean no comma or parentheses or anything between.

Comment: I've removed the code with ScrollReveal()... Please take a look at it now.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the same error. Can you add a screenshot of the error to your question?

Comment: Yeah Sure, Please check it now.

Comment: So that's an error from linter or compiler. Since you removed some code, what is on line 11 now? Also it seems it is line 11 from minified main.min.js file but can you show the original code before minification?

Comment: Line 11 is the same line mentioned in above code.